# Angularjs iterate over $http rest call with previous result

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest

When making a call to a $http resource when iterating over an array the locations array becomes inconsistent because of the i variable being updated before the locationService result comes back.

```
homeService.get($scope.name).then(function (homes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++) {
        locationService.get(homes[i]).then(function (result) {
            locations.push(result);
        });
    }
});
```

How can I achieve iterating over an array making a $http call and update the i variable after the locationService result? Thus having the locations array being updated consistently.

Comment: you want to keep the location array in order, with the order of homes?

Comment: Hi Quanyue, no not in order of homes. The problem is in the iteration block it is making a ajax call and the iteration goes on without waiting for the result of the ajax service.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't see the problem. once the service is called, when it returns, your locations array will be inserted, even if the iteration doesn't wait for the response.

Comment: Hi Qianyue, thank you. After reading that you do not see a problem I fine combed all my services and found that one do not have a return promise which means the result never gets set and updated.